# didSet not updating UILabel.text with async data

Tags: uilabel, viewcontroller, appdelegate, didset

I am trying to show the username of a logged-in user when logging in using googleSignIn. The googleSignIn has been set up in appdelegate and the username to display is in the viewController that launches the sign in.

For a strange reason, I can "Print" the name that is being passed in from appDelegate but not set the UILable.text. For that matter, I cannot even set the UILabel.text to any static content from inside the didSet.

```
//APP DELEGATE
    var vc: ViewController?

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if let error = error {
           if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
             print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
           } else {
             print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
           return
         }
        vc?.userID = user.profile.name
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
    }


// MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER

    var userID: String? {
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let name = self.userID {
                self.welcomeLabel?.text = name
            }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that VC holds the right reference of main view controller. You can set breakpoint and debug.
2. make sure that welcomeLabel @IBoutlet has been connected.
3. You have declared your welcomeLabel as non-optional but during it is usage you are trying to unwrap it optionaly which could be the reason for your error. Try change the below code

   ```
   self.welcomeLabel?.text = name

    To

   self.welcomeLabel.text = name
   ```